# How to display a datatables editor for a table that has a primary key and a foreign key reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

My tables are like so:

```
User
---------
Id (type string, primary key)


Professional
--------------------
Id (int, primary key)
UserId (string, foreign key references User.Id)
Field 1 (string)
Field 2 (string)
Field 3 (date time)
```

I am designing an ASP.NET MVC View (and controller) to perform CRUD operations on the Professional table.

My question specifically is, what changes should I make to the editor options and the datatable options in order to:

1. Not display the `Id` and the `UserId` fields of the Professional
   table in the user interface;
2. But the values of these fields must be passed back and forth between
   the client and my ASP.NET MVC web application;
3. How do I tell editor or the datatable about the primary key and
   foreign key relationships so it maintains referential integrity?

Comment: if you're using jquery datatables are you using an ajax call to populate?

Comment: @code Please correct me if I am wrong but I believe that that's the only way to load data onto a client from a server? I have just an hour's or more of acquaintance with jQuery datatables.

Comment: @code: To answer your question, yes, I am using jQuery datatables and yes, I am loading data using an ajax call. Haven't run the code yet. Was wondering if there was a way to tell the editor and the datatable objects at the client side and the Editor object at the server side about the foreign key.

Comment: I see what you're saying now not sure about that one